# Canonical url for product with multiple categories

Tags: categories, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm building a shop using Craft Commerce where a single product can be assigned to multiple categories. The url structure I'm using for the product detail page is: http://domain.com/category/product-url

In an effort to avoid being penalised for duplicate content I would like to set the canonical URL for my product detail page by always pulling the first category as the canonical URL in the meta. I've tried a few things but keep getting stuck - any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `{{ entry.categoryFieldHandle[0].slug }}`. The `[0]` simply grabs the first category in the field.

You will need to make sure there is always at least one category allocated to an entry or you'll get an error.